# AngularJS Custom input control not performing validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a custom input control and trying to perform certain validation on blur.
But its not performing as expected. I want to use template like below instead of using jquery specific element.bind('blur')

```
 template: '<input type="text" ng-blur="performvalidation()">',
```

[Complete fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ggcoder81/hkg9v90s/2/)

Please guide or correct what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more code . So we can understand what you are  trying to do .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create custom validators you should add them to the ngModelController's $validators field. e.g.

```
angular.module('app').directive('strongSecret', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.uppercaseValidator = function(value) {
        return /[A-Z]/.test(value);
      }

      ctrl.$validators.numberValidator = function(value) {
        return /[0-9]/.test(value);
      }

      ctrl.$validators.sixCharactersValidator = function(value) {
        return value.length === 6;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Also instead of giving your directive a template you should just use it on an input element

```
<input ng-model="strongSecret" strong-secret name="strongSecret"/>
```

if you don't want to show the errors until the user clicks away from the input field you could do this

```
<ul ng-if="sampleForm.strongSecret.$touched" class="error-msgs" ng-messages="sampleForm.strongSecret.$error">
...
</ul>
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e81kee9z/2/